# Unable to show a checkbox using Jade and Node

Tags: node.js, pug

Trying to do a checkbox to select Male or Female.

Code to show the CheckBox is as follows;

```
span(style='display:block;')
    div.
        Sex:
    input(type='radio',id='Male',name='sex',value='Male')
        Male
    input(type='radio',id='Female',name='sex',value='Female')
        Female
```

However when The page is shown I get the following;

**28| Sex: 
 29| input(type='radio',id='Male',name='sex',value='Male') 
 > 30| 'Male' 
 31| input(type='radio',id='Female',name='sex',value='Female') 
 32| 
         33| 
name is not defined
28| Sex:
29| input(type='radio',id='Male',name='sex',value='Male')

> 30| 'Male'
>   31| input(type='radio',id='Female',name='sex',value='Female')
>   32|
>   33|**

How can you show a checkbox using Jade with two options 'Male' & 'Female'

(I have tried putting a '.' after the input line, and tried putting Male into both single and double quotes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not allowed to shift into a self closing tag and also you get an error because of not [piping](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#pipedtext) your "labels", so *Jade* thinks they are vars.

Please try this:

```
span(style='display:block;')
    div
        | Sex:
        input(type='radio',id='Male',name='sex',value='Male')
        | Male
        input(type='radio',id='Female',name='sex',value='Female')
        | Female
```

To produce this HTML: [as JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjBk9/1/)

```
<span style="display:block;">
  <div>Sex:
    <input type="radio" id="Male" name="sex" value="Male"/>Male
    <input type="radio" id="Female" name="sex" value="Female"/>Female 
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @ztirom - that did it, although I made some minor changes to fit in with the rest of the page

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
span(style='display:block;')
    div
        p Sex:
        label
            input(type='radio',id='Male',name='sex',value='Male')
                | Male
        label
            input(type='radio',id='Female',name='sex',value='Female')
                | Female
```